# После создания объекта заполненное поле объекта возвращает null

Tags: c#

Имеется массив простейших объектов, который я загоняю в конструктор другого класса через params. В созданном объекте поле, для которого используется массив, возвращает null. Проходил отладчиком, в конструкторе проходит все следуя логике.

Формирование массива и вызов конструктора:

```
Coordinats[] coordinats = {
new Coordinats(0, 8), 
new Coordinats(0, 15), 
new Coordinats(0, 22), 
new Coordinats(0, 29)
};
listSelectData.Add(new ListSelectLines(queryText, coordinats));
```

Класс ListSelectLines:

```
public class ListSelectLines 
{
  public Coordinats CoordinatsPosition { set; get; }
  public List<Coordinats> CoordinatsPositionOnDate { set; get; }
  public string SelectLine { set; get; }

  public ListSelectLines(string selectLines, params Coordinats[] coordinatXY)
  {
    List<Coordinats> CoordinatsPositionOnDate = new List<Coordinats>();
    foreach (var coord in coordinatXY)
    {
      if (coord.ColNumber >= 0 && coord.RowNumber >= 0)
      {
         CoordinatsPositionOnDate.Add(coord);
      }
    }
    SelectLine = string.Empty;
    if (selectLines != null || selectLines != string.Empty)
    {
      SelectLine = selectLines;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: кстати условие 

    if (selectLines != null || selectLines != string.Empty)

бессмысленно, поскольку оно всегда истинно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас в конструкторе ошибка - вы создаете новую коллекцию вместо того, что бы работать с полем класса

> List<Coordinats> CoordinatsPositionOnDate = new List<Coordinats>();

Измените на

```
this.CoordinatsPositionOnDate = new List<Coordinats>();
```

Comment: Элементарный вариант и не пришел в голову =( под вечер пятницы не о работе думается. 
А о бессмысленности не совсем так - в случае с работой с DevExpress'ными SQLDataSource, SQLDataReader вполне можно ожидать и false.